# Python : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'start'

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, nltk, nltk-book

The below code belongs to NLTK regex:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

scene = "Hello how! how are you? what is your problem. Can I solve with 00code for you/ by the way bye. Take care"

match_index = print(re.search("you",scene))
print(match_index.start(),match_index.end())
```

Error I got is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-5e13e5437c3e> in <module>()
----> 1 print(match_index.start(),match_index.end())

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'start'
```

I have included its library but still, it is showing an error. What
are the ways I can handle this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
match_index = print(re.search("you",scene))
```

`print` returns None, so after this line, `match_index` is None.

Try assigning and printing on separate lines.

```
match_index = re.search("you",scene)
print(match_index)
```

Result:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(19, 22), match='you'>
19 22
```

Comment: Sir, I executed the code like this:                                                                 
`match_index = print(re.search("you",scene))`
`print(match_index)`                                                                                                                                         `print(match_index.start(),match_index.end())`

Comment: As I said, `match_index = print(re.search("you",scene))` will not work. Do `match_index = re.search("you",scene)` instead.